# Why I cannot display Firebase data in ListView

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone help me in this problem, I try to display job from the firebase in Listview, but it doesn't display anything! I have tried different codes from topic at stack and different sites but receive error at

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,retrieve());
```

and this

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

with nullexception

**Javacode**

```
package com.gumption.zeeshanahmed.jobaps;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast; 
import com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class EditsJobs extends AppCompatActivity {

     ListView lv;
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
     ArrayList<String> spacecrafts=new ArrayList<>();

// Declaring String variable ( In which we are storing firebase server URL 
//).
     public static final String Firebase_Server_URL = 
     "https://jobaps70.firebaseio.com/";

// Declaring String variables to store name & phone number get from 
//EditText.
      String PriceHolder, JobDescriptionHolder;
      FirebaseHelper helper;

// Declaring Firebase object.
      Firebase firebase;

// Creating FirebaseAuth.
      FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth ;

// Creating FirebaseAuth.
      FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

// Creating Boolean variable that holds EditText is empty or not status.
      Boolean EditTextStatus ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edits_jobs);

//Actionbar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
    ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.Snow)));

// Adding MainActivity context into Firebase context.

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(EditsJobs.this);

// Passing firebase Server URL into firebase object.

    firebase = new Firebase(Firebase_Server_URL);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

// On activity start check whether there is user previously logged in or 
//   not.

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){

        // Finishing current Profile activity.
        finish();

        // If user already not log in then Redirect to LoginActivity .
        Intent intent = new Intent(EditsJobs.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        // Showing toast message.
        Toast.makeText(EditsJobs.this, "Please Log in to continue", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    // Adding firebaseAuth current user info into firebaseUser object.
    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    // Getting logged in user email from firebaseUser.getEmail() method and 
     set into TextView.
    setTitle( firebaseUser.getEmail());
    setTitleColor(R.color.DarkGray);

    // ListView element

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.datadisplist);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,retrieve());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
        position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(EditsJobs.this, retrieve().get(position), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    });


}

 private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
    jobsdetails.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        String jobs=ds.getValue(JobDetails.class).getjob();
        jobsdetails.add(jobs);
    }
}

//RETRIEVE
public ArrayList<String> retrieve(){
firebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        fetchData(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        fetchData(dataSnapshot);

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }

});


return spacecrafts;
}
}
```

**XML**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.gumption.zeeshanahmed.jobaps.EditsJobs">
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/texteditjobs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_edit_jobs"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/datadisplist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/texteditjobs"
        android:background="@color/Khaki"/>
       </RelativeLayout>
```

**JobDetail**

```
 public class JobDetails {

    private String price;
    private String jobDescription;
    private String jobSpinner;
    public String email;
    public JobDetails() {
        // This is default constructor.
    }

    public String getPrice() {

        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String pri) {

        this.price = pri;
    }

    public String getjobDescription() {

        return jobDescription;

    }

    public void setjobDescription(String jobd) {

        this.jobDescription = jobd;
    }

    public void setjob(String jry) {

        this.jobSpinner = jry ;

    }

    public String getjob() {

        return jobSpinner;

    }

    public void setemail(String jel) {

        this.email = jel ;

    }

    public String getemail() {

        return email;

    }
}
```

**Using textView**

when i use text view the data is displayed only one atmost!

```
// Adding click listener to Show data button.
    ShowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Adding addValueEventListener method on firebase object.
            firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot MainSnapshot) {

              for (DataSnapshot SubSnapshot : MainSnapshot.getChildren()) {

              JobDetails jobdetails =SubSnapshot.getValue(JobDetails.class);
                    for
                        // Adding name and phone number of student into 
                      string that is coming from server.

                        String ShowDataString = "Job: " + 
                        jobdetails.getjob() + "\nJob Description: " + 
                        jobdetails.getjobDescription() + "\n\n";

                        // Apply complete string variable into TextView.
                        ShowDataTextView.setText(ShowDataString);
               }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    System.out.println("Data Access Failed" + 
                firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
        });
```

**with Xml**

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/showmetadata"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/show"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

It will be very helpful if someone help will me with this. Please and thank 
you!

**Tried listview **

Now i tried listview, and it crashes here is the code and error

```
 public class WorkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//    Spinner jobSpin;

ListView lv;
Button ShowButton;
// Define a String ArrayList for the job
private ArrayList<String> jobdes=new ArrayList<>();

// Define an ArrayAdapter for the list
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

// Declaring String variable ( In which we are storing firebase server URL 
).
public static final String Firebase_Server_URL = 
"https://jobaps70.firebaseio.com/";
public static final String Firebase_Server_URL1 = 
 "https://jobaps70.firebaseio.com/jobs";

// Declaring String variables to store name & phone number get from 
EditText.
String PriceHolder, JobDescriptionHolder;
FirebaseHelper helper;

// Declaring Firebase object.
Firebase firebase,firebase1;

// Creating FirebaseAuth.
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth ;

// Creating FirebaseAuth.
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

// Creating Boolean variable that holds EditText is empty or not status.
Boolean EditTextStatus ;


TextView ShowDataTextView ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edits_jobs);

      //        Actionbar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
    ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.Snow)));

    ShowButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.show);

    // Adding MainActivity context into Firebase context.
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(WorkActivity.this);

    // Passing firebase Server URL into firebase object.
    firebase = new Firebase(Firebase_Server_URL);
    firebase1=new Firebase(Firebase_Server_URL1);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // On activity start check whether there is user previously logged in or 
       not.
    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){

        // Finishing current Profile activity.
        finish();

        // If user already not log in then Redirect to LoginActivity .
        Intent intent = new Intent(WorkActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        // Showing toast message.
        Toast.makeText(WorkActivity.this, "Please Log in to continue", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    // Adding firebaseAuth current user info into firebaseUser object.
    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    // Getting logged in user email from firebaseUser.getEmail() method and 
        set into TextView.
    setTitle( firebaseUser.getEmail());
    setTitleColor(R.color.DarkGray);
      firebase.child("jobs");

    // Associate the jobs' list with the corresponding ListView
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvshow);

    // Set the ArrayAdapter to the ListView
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, jobdes);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    // Attach a ChildEventListener to the teacher database, so we can 
          retrieve the job entries
    firebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            // Get the value from the DataSnapshot and add it to the jobs' 
         list
            JobDetails jo = (JobDetails) 
         dataSnapshot.getValue(JobDetails.class);
            String joString = String.valueOf(jo);
            arrayAdapter.add(joString);
 //

            // Notify the ArrayAdapter that there was a change
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.gumption.zeeshanahmed.jobaps, PID: 4774
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
              ComponentInfo{com.gumption.zeeshanahmed.jobaps/
              com.gumption.zeeshanahmed.jobaps.WorkActivity}: 
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
              method 'void 
             android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' 
             on a null object reference at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
 (ZygoteInit.java:726) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main 
 (ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a 
 null object reference at 
 com.gumption.zeeshanahmed.jobaps.WorkActivity.onCreate
 (WorkActivity.java:109)
              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) at 
 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
 (Instrumentation.java:1107) at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
 (ActivityThread.java:2369)atandroid.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
 (ActivityThread.java:2476) at android.app.ActivityThread.-
  wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
 (ActivityThread.java:1344) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
 (Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
 (ZygoteInit.java:726) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
 (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**java Error line**

It is showing error at this

```
 lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is `retrieve()`, which is a method that returns an `ArrayList<String>` named `spacecrafts`. This `ArrayList<String>` is initialized in the first lines of your code but never updated. With other words, you are using `spacecrafts` in your adapter which is empty.

To solve this problem, every time you get data from your Firebase add it to the right `ArrayList<String>`. One more thing to node, due the asynchronous behaviour of those methods, you cannot return an `ArrayList<String>` in the way you do because it will always be empty. You need to declare and use/update that ArrayList inside that method.

Comment: Have you managed to fill the ArrayList with Strings? To use the correct one?

Comment: i updated the question! when i use text view it work fine but display only first 
row values

Comment: it takes about 5- 10 sec.

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked. Try to use `Log.d("TAG", ShowDataString);`. Are all the values displayed?

Comment: log show all the data, the text view is only showing last value in logcat. what should i do? any suggestion!

Comment: i updated the question! when i use listview it crashes

Comment: This is basically another question, but as i see, you have a NPE becase either your `lv` is null or your `ArrayAdaper` is null. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. Do you think that my answer helped for the initial question?

Comment: yes it does and i will post a new question see you there, until a very good tic and day 2 you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are populating data too early. when you call retrieve() method it runs immediately and return an empty Arrylist. Firebase dosen't give you data instantly. It makes some delay while getting the data. so get all data first then populate your adapter.

or use

```
adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

after getting data.